# ASP.NET MVC web application loading the wrong shared layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am creating an ASP.NET MVC web application based on the Visual Studio template with 2 shared layouts, 1 for the Backoffice - `_Layout.cshtml` - and another for the mobile web app - `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml`.

The issue is that when I load the backoffice home page in Chrome, it loads the `_Layout.cshtml` file, but when I activate the mobile device simulator, it loads the `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml` file.

The same happens on a mobile device, if I go to the default index view of the home controller, it loads the `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml` file.

I tried to debug but I don't find the place where the system changes to `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml`.

The only way I found to avoid that is to rename `_Layout.Mobile.cshtml` to `__Layout.Mobile.cshtml` and then it loads the `_Layout.cshtml` correctly.

I don't really don't know where to start looking for the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any view with .Mobile extension will be automatically used if `Request.Browser.IsMobileDevice = true`

Found At: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions/aspnet-mvc-4-mobile-features

> A significant new feature in ASP.NET MVC 4 is a simple mechanism that
> lets you override any view (including layouts and partial views) for
> mobile browsers in general, for an individual mobile browser, or for
> any specific browser. To provide a mobile-specific view, you can copy
> a view file and add .Mobile to the file name. For example, to create a
> mobile Index view, copy Views\Home\Index.cshtml to
> Views\Home\Index.Mobile.cshtml.

Comment: Thanks! What a coincidence to give the name _Layout.Mobile.cshtml to the Layout for the mobile Views.

Comment: the one who knows, knows ;) (argentinean expression)

Comment: Here in Portugal is "Quem sabe, sabe!" - it's basically the same :)